# @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) not mapping with @XmlElement

Tags: json, xml, rest, xml-parsing, resttemplate

POST call is using property variable names instead of @XmlElement(name)

**DTO**:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "balance",
    "companyName",
    ...

@XmlRootElement(name = "CustomerDTO", namespace = "")
public class CustomerDTO {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "", required = true)
    protected String balance;
    @XmlElement(name = "company_name", namespace = "", required = true)
    protected String companyName;
```

**POST call**:

```
HttpEntity<CustomerDTO> entity = new HttpEntity(customerDTO, headers);
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, entity, String.class);
```

The problem is that final JSON is getting created as `companyName` instead of `company_name`

Comment: any reason why you went with xml tags for json data ?

Comment: After some digging you might have a conflict between the tags you have. In your propOrder you have `companyName`. Replace that with `company_name`

Comment: @Coder: None. Its just a stupid convention that we are following in our project !!!
Replacing is not exactly an option because the DTO is getting generated through a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marshall and un-marshall the DTO:

```
private String marshallTOJSON(CustomerDTO customerDTO) throws JAXBException {
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");
        JAXBContext context = JSONJAXBContext.newInstance(CustomerDTO.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        JSONMarshaller jsonMarshaller = JSONJAXBContext.getJSONMarshaller(marshaller, context);
        jsonMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        jsonMarshaller.marshallToJSON(customerDTO, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@XmlElement changes the field name for xml request and not for json,
If you want to rename the variable for JSON then you should use **@JsonProperty("Name")**

```
For e.g:
public class Test {
  @JsonProperty("first_name")
  public String firstName;
  @JsonProperty("last_name")
  public String lastName; 
}
```

o/p for json will be

```
"Test":{
  "first_name":"Parameter-Name",
  "last_name":"Parameter-Value"
}
```

Comment: Not an option for me as I can't make a change in DTO (it is getting generated automatically through a script).